# My filter error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote test filter, that must return constant data.

```
mainApp.filter('dateParser', function () {
    return function (param) {
        return [{id:1,day:'23.07.17'},{id:2,day:'22.07.17'}];
    };
});
```

However when I whant it like that:

```
<td ng-repeat="crrDay in studentOne.daysList|dateParser">
        {{day.currentVal}}
</td>
```

I get these data but in console get an error:

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig
Infinite $digest Loop
```

Please tell me why this is happening?

**UPDATE**
full filter

```
mainApp.filter('dateParser', function () {
    console.log(this);
    return function (param) {

        var parse, sorted, result = [], parsedArray = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
            parse = param[i].day.split('.');
            parsedArray[i] = {
                'id': param[i].id,
                'day': parse[0],
                'month': parse[1],
                'year': parse[2]
            };
        }
        sorted = _.sortBy(parsedArray, ['year', 'month', 'day']);
        for (i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
            result[i] = {
                id:sorted[i].id,
                day: sorted[i].day + '.' + sorted[i].month + '.' + sorted[i].year
            };
        }
        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: I understand what this error means in the general case, but I do not know why it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning function inside a function, change your filter as,

```
mainApp.filter('dateParser', function () {
     return [{id:1,day:'23.07.17'},{id:2,day:'22.07.17'}];
});
```

**`function(param)`** does nothing here.

**EDIT**

If you need to accept a param, do it like this,

```
mainApp.filter("dateParser", function() { 
   return function(input) { 
      //do your process and return
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I need to receive this variable(param)?
 cut out all the code so that it would be easier for you to read it.

Comment: @Vitamine_R you can accept a parameter as edited above

Comment: If I do as you wrote I get an error:
`Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: paramProvider <- param <- dateParserFilter`

Comment: If that's what I want to get a full array `studentOne.daysList`
inside my filter

Comment: ok i think everytime it creates a new array, can you post the implementation of filter.

Comment: I update my post, but i test with constant, as I wrote in the post and got the same error

Comment: ok if you are doing so, you are nowhere passing the parameter in html

Comment: that is angular.js 1.66

Comment: How should I do something to receive  dataList.daysList in the filter and in the recoil did not happen this error?